# Use string input of parent function as parameters for another

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function that returns the gradient function of a given formula. A minimal example of this would be (without encapsulating it in a function):

```
f1 <- deriv(y ~ a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2, c('a0', 'a1', 'a2'), function(a0, a1, a2, x){} )

grad <- attr(f1(a0 = 1, a1 = 2, a2 = 1.5, x = 3),"gradient")
```

I know f1 doesn't depend on a, b and c as it's linear, but it could potentially do.

Now, I would like to create a function that takes a formula and variables and returns `f1` as in the example. Some outline (not working) would be:

```
gradient_function <- function(formula, variables){
    f1 <- deriv(formula, variables, function(variables, x){} )
    return(f1)
}
```

The problem lies in how to tell R that the second time I use `variables`, it's the argument of the function that gets created from `deriv`.

I've searched for a while and the only working solution, which feels pretty wonky and poses some extra annoyance when one wants to evaluate the function with named parameters, is `eval(parse())`, which also means using single and double quotes, the whole expression to get something like:

But I was wondering if there's a better way that I don't know about and that wouldn't imply building a gruesome string.

```
formula <- y ~ a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2

vars <- paste0("a", 0:2)

vector <- "c('a0', 'a1', 'a2')"

eval(parse(text = paste0("f2 <- deriv(", formula, ",", variables, ", function(", paste(vars, collapse=","),", x){} )")))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without passing a character vector at all - just using bare variables as input. You can use something like the following function:

```r
my_func <- function(form, ...)
{
  vars <- as.list(match.call())[-(1:2)]
  char_vars <- sapply(vars, as.character)
  arglist <- lapply(char_vars, function(x) NULL)
  f <- as.function(append(setNames(arglist, char_vars), quote({})))
  deriv(form, char_vars, f)
}
```

Which allows you to make `f1` like this:

```
f1 <- my_func(y ~ a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2, a0, a1, a2, x)
```

And this gives the same result as the original:

```
grad <- attr(f1(a0 = 1, a1 = 2, a2 = 1.5, x = 3), "gradient")

grad
#>      a0 a1 a2  x
#> [1,]  1  3  9 11
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are a few things that I'd like to add/ask:
- To get the same answer you'd need to use `deriv(form, char_vars[-length(char_vars)], f)` so it doesn't take the variable `x` in deriv.
- Sorry to complicate the problem, as I tried to simplify it for the question, but would it be possible to have more arguments in the parent function without this collapsing? Namely the actual value of `a0`, `a1`... (`a0_value`...) such that inside the function it could be evaluated:
`grad <- attr(f1(a0 = a0_value, a1 = a1_value, a2 = a2_value, x = 3), "gradient")`